# how to select cell from a plane using vtkselection?

Tags: c++, vtk

I am a new user of vtk, I'm trying to draw a heatmap with vtk by coloring a plane , and then to interact with it so it can link to some other view, but I don't know how to interact with it, can anyone help me with this? and will a vtkselection work?  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?
http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/PolyData/TriangleColoredPoints

If not, you'll have to clarify your problem. I don't understand what you mean by "link it to some other view".